# How to make items in a FMX TListBox bold?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

How can I make the items in my FMX `TListBox` bold? I can't find anything by myself, either in the documentation or the Internet.

Comment: As you have noted, there's no setting for that. What would you use it for, if it was possible? There might be some other way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I just want to make the text inside the ListBox easier to read. And for that bold text is the better option for me.

Comment: I don't work with FMX. Does it support owner-drawing the items? Or placing controls inside each item, like a `TLabel` with its `Font.Style` set to `fsBold`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gregg who gave a working answer for delphi, i'll put a C++Builder version here.

I made a loop over my ListBox with the item count, and it does not affect the loading speed of the ListBox (around 4000 items in my case) so it's a good solution at least for me.

```
ListBox->ListItems[x]->StyledSettings = ListBox->ListItems[x]->StyledSettings >> TStyledSetting::Style;
ListBox->ListItems[x]->Font->Style = ListBox->ListItems[x]->Font->Style << fsBold;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set two properties for the tListItem in question.  The first line of code below lets you set the font properties for that ListItem rather than having the style dictate the font properties (if you miss this step, the next step will have no affect). The second line sets that ListItem to bold (where, of course, x is the index within the list that should be made bold)

```
ListBox1.ListItems[x].StyledSettings:=[];
ListBox1.ListItems[x].Font.Style:=[TFontStyle.fsBold];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom theme for TListBoxItems. Create one by right mouse on ListBox.

Comment: I should have precised that but i get the items to display into the ListBox from a database.

Comment: It does not matter. You create a separate style that itself applies to all elements.